# rosws problem groovy

Tags: ros, rosws, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
when i use `rosws init ~/groovy_workspace /opt/ros/groovy` on terminal i got this problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosws", line 54, in <module>
    from rosinstall.common import MultiProjectException
ImportError: No module named commo
```

i didn’t have any problems on fuerte, How could i fix this?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113761/rosws-problem-groovy/) by [Mahyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/4281/mahyar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on the version of `python-rosinstall` you have installed, this might be related to [rosinstall/issues/89](https://github.com/vcstools/rosinstall/issues/89).

Some of the classes / scripts `rosws` uses were moved to another module, but not all the references to those classes were updated. Version 0.7.2 should fix that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-30**:
Make sure you have the latest debian packages and are not using older ones installed via PIP.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try “sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall”

---

Originally posted by [Jack Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/10321/jack-fu/) with karma: 11 on 2013-12-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1